# What's the correct way to accumulate NSDecimalNumber values?

Tags: objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I am trying to accumulate NSDecimalNumber values obtained from an array (*apptDataArray*, obtained from a CoreData store; aCurrentCharges is defined as NSDecimalNumber).  This is my code:

```
        NSDecimalNumber *accumulatedFees = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < apptDataArray.count; i++)  {
            AppointmentInfo *currentAppointment = [apptDataArray objectAtIndex: i];
            accumulatedFees = [accumulatedFees decimalNumberByAdding: currentAppointment.aCurrentCharges];  //  <----  not accumulating
        }
        oAccumulatedCharges.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",accumulatedFees];
```

My problem is the line marked *not accumulating* is doing just that -- not accumulating.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `accumulatedFees` is not being initialized correctly. Try setting it this way:

```
NSDecimalNumber *accumulatedFees = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
```

Comment: Unbelievable!  Thank you so much... NSDecimalNumbers are very confusing sometimes! :D